# How to disable navigationBar animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationbar, navigationbar

I have two UITableViewControllers such that when I click next on the first UITableViewController, the second UITableViewController gets pushed on the navigation stack and animates the transition like normal. I'd like to make it so when I push next, only the views animate, and the navigation bar doesn't (stays the same). I've gotten very close to doing this with the code below:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    CATransition *navTransition = [CATransition animation];
    navTransition.duration = .5;
    navTransition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    navTransition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    navTransition.subtype = kCATransitionPush;
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer addAnimation:navTransition forKey:nil];

}
```

I put this code, and I also make it so the title and buttons on both navigation bars are  exactly same in each UITableViewController. It almost works, problem is, the navigation bar blinks when the animation occurs. Is there anyway to get it to not blink, or is there any other good way to prevent the animation of the navbar from occurring (ie disabling the animation on the layer or something)?

UPDATE: Anyone got any other ideas? Still struggling with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I came up with. Here is the code for the first viewController in the sequence:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
        if (viewController == self)
        {
                if (self.isInitialized)
                {
                        CATransition *navigationBarAnimation = [CATransition animation];
                        navigationBarAnimation.duration = 1.5;
                        navigationBarAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];;
                        navigationBarAnimation.type = kCATransitionFade;
                        navigationBarAnimation.subtype = kCATransitionFade;
                        navigationBarAnimation.removedOnCompletion = YES;
                        [self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer addAnimation:navigationBarAnimation forKey:nil];
                }
                else 
                {
                        self.isInitialized = YES;
                }
        }
}

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
        if (viewController == self)
        {
                if (self.isInitialized)
                {
                        [self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer removeAllAnimations];
                }
        }
}
```

Here is the code for the 2nd view controller:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
        if (viewController == self)
        {
                if (!self.isInitialized)
                {
                        CATransition *navigationBarAnimation = [CATransition animation];
                        navigationBarAnimation.duration = 1.5;
                        navigationBarAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];;
                        navigationBarAnimation.type = kCATransitionFade;
                        navigationBarAnimation.subtype = kCATransitionFade;
                        navigationBarAnimation.removedOnCompletion = YES;
                        [self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer addAnimation:navigationBarAnimation forKey:nil];
                        self.isInitialized = YES;
                }
        }
}

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
        if (viewController == self)
        {
                if (self.isInitialized)
                {
                        [self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer removeAllAnimations];
                }
        }
}
```

You have to use the `UINavigationController` delegate methods to figure out when the `UIViewController` is being shown. Then for each `UIViewController`, need to make a `BOOL` `isInitialized` property so it helps you determine when the `UIViewController` is being pushed on the stack, or when it's being shown because you pushed back on the next `UIViewController`.

Comment: I'm using the animation code in viewDidLoad, but I'm not sure when, where and if I should be using removeAllAnimations, have you any further comments to make ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Jules - I updated the answer with a lot more detail. Try this out and let me know how it goes. Everything should work fine up there, but I did this a while ago so let me know.

Comment: Subclass `UINavigationBar` and override `popNavigationItemAnimated`   http://www.petersimpson.me/blog/static-nav-bar/

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the best answer/idea but you could just mask the UINavigationBar during the animation.

Create a `UINavigationBar` that looks exactly the same way as your current `UNavigationBar` add it to the `keyWindow` just before the transition takes place, then after it is finished remove it. This will essentially cover just the `UINavigationBar` and hide its animation.

Comment: Cool idea will try this out if I can't get the other way to work

Answer (score 0):

**Swift**

Here is solution in swift

```
var isInitialized = false
```

*Your FirstViewController:*

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        if viewController == self {
            if self.isInitialized {
                var navigationBarAnimation = CATransition()
                navigationBarAnimation.duration = 1.5
                navigationBarAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn)
                navigationBarAnimation.type = kCATransitionFade
                navigationBarAnimation.subtype = kCATransitionFade
                navigationBarAnimation.removedOnCompletion = true
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar?.layer?.addAnimation(navigationBarAnimation, forKey: nil)
                }
                else 
                {
                        self.isInitialized = true;
                }
        }
}

func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        if viewController == self {
            if self.isInitialized {
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar?.layer?.removeAllAnimations()
            }
        }
}
```

*Your SecondViewController:*

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        if viewController == self {
            if !self.isInitialized {
                var navigationBarAnimation = CATransition()
                navigationBarAnimation.duration = 1.5
                navigationBarAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn)
                navigationBarAnimation.type = kCATransitionFade
                navigationBarAnimation.subtype = kCATransitionFade
                navigationBarAnimation.removedOnCompletion = true
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar?.layer?.addAnimation(navigationBarAnimation, forKey: nil)
                        self.isInitialized = true;
                }
        }
}

func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        if viewController == self {
            if self.isInitialized {
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar?.layer?.removeAllAnimations()
            }
        }
}
```