# pushViewController without title animation

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I push Viewcontroller using this code:

```
 if (! self.infoViewController) {
     self.infoViewController = [[InfoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InfoViewController" bundle:nil];
 }
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7f
                     animations:^{
                         [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
                         [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.infoViewController animated:NO];
                         [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
                     }];
```

Is it possible to disable navigationBar title animation? It's slide from left during animation.

Comment: possible duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717742/how-to-disable-navigationbar-animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry. Here is the answer:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.7f
                 animations:^{
                     [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
                     [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
                 }];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.infoViewController animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 1):

Push your ViewController without animation like this:

```
if (! self.infoViewController) {
     self.infoViewController = [[InfoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InfoViewController" bundle:nil];
 }
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.infoViewController animated:NO];
```

this will not animate ur pushing title. I hope this will helps u.

Comment: I want flip animation of the view. I just need to disable animation of title lable in navigation bar.